# Using raw sql in rails raising PG::InFailedSqlTransaction

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following sql query (picked from this [article](http://crossingtheruby.com/2013/12/15/time-series-with-postgresql.html):

```
SELECT
  date,
  coalesce(count,0) AS count
FROM
  generate_series(
      '2013-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,
      '2013-12-31 00:00'::timestamp,
      '1 day') AS date
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT
     date_trunc('day', users.created_at) as day,
     count(users.id) as count
   FROM users
   WHERE
     created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00'
     AND created_at < '2013-12-31 00:00'
   GROUP BY day) results
    ON (date = results.day) ;
```

I want to use it in rails and i want to make the time appears as a unix timestamp

In previous i was using this method which is causing freezing to my OS:

```
  def yearly_chart
    start_year = Time.now.beginning_of_year.to_i*1000
    end_year = Time.now.to_i*1000
    all_tickets = Ticket.all

    count_for_year = (start_year..end_year).map do |year|
      [ year, all_tickets.select{|t| t.created_at.to_time.to_i*1000 == year }.count ]
    end
    @yearly_complaints = count_for_year
  end
```

I already tried `Find_by_sql` but its not working and raising:

```
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Also I have tested  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` in console which is not working also

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's possibly because you're not really asking a question. Are you trying to figure out why your machine is freezing? What is your question?

Comment: no my question is : I want to use the above sql query in rails and i want to make the time appears as a unix timestamp

Comment: StackOverflow is for answers to a specific error or problem, not for telling you how to code.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: and i am not asking how to code , i am asking for a better way because i have an issue and i am looking for a solution ! is this against stackoverflow rules ? i am asking after trying and searching on google

Comment: Have you tried your SQL in `psql` to make sure it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: yes i have tested it in Rubymine sql console and it works as expected , but i want to change the date to unix stamp , which i don't know how to change it in case of series , and i tried to use the current query in rails but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_by_sql`.

ActiveRecord is for assembling redundant & prosaic SQL queries out of a schema. Your query is neither redundant nor straightforward, so just send the raw query that you have already invented.

Comment: tested and not working, raises `PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: i tried to use it for a single query but it did not show any resut:
 `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('Select * From users')
   (2.3ms)  Select * From users
 => #<PG::Result:0xac3b9f0> `

Comment: Look up how to get records out of the PG::Result now

Comment: even if it work for the select * users , its not work for my query which is in my question